# How can I prevent a lambda function from calling itself recursively?

Tags: python, lambda

In my code, I first define two lambda functions:

```
func1 = lambda x: x + 2
func2 = lambda x: x * 2
```

and later in my code, I want to create a lambda function that adds the results of the two lambda functions above, but this function must have the same name as one of the functions above. That is, I wanted to do something like this:

```
func2 = lambda x: func1(x) + func2(x)
```

Notice the function name `func2` appears again.

I know this is silly and there are other ways of achieving the same desired outcome. However this example is just a very simplified version of what I tried to achieve. However, this won't work, as it gives me the error:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

I think that's because `func2` keeps calling itself. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I cannot change the names `func1` or `func2` (note that also means I cannot create two new functions with different names but the same content). I tried something like this

```
func2Copy = lambda x: func2(x)
func1Copy = lambda x: func1(x)
func2 = lambda x: func1Copy(x) + func2Copy(x)
```

but saw the same error (as expected). Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why you can't simply do `swap = func2` `func2 = lambda x: func1(x) + swap(x)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use some indirection

```
func2 = (lambda f1, f2: lambda x: f1(x) + f2(x))(func1, func2)
```

so then

```
>>> func2(1)
5
```

This is a bit silly though - the short story is you need another function.

Answer (score 4):

You need to save a reference of the original functions. A quick and dirty way to achieve this is to make them default parameters to your lambda.

```
func2 = lambda x, func1=func1, func2=func2: func1(x) + func2(x)
```

Otherwise, a much more safe way to do this is to create a function that would return your altered function.

```
def new_func2(func1, func2):
    return lambda x: func1(x) + func2(x)
func2 = new_func2(func1, func2)
```